# android: adding dynamically with dynamically items

Tags: java, android

**i have list item in each row like :**

item1 item2 item3 item4 item5 item6

**I need**

item 1 item 2 item3

item 4 item5 item 6
...

I don't need to use GridView. My getView():

```
               LinearLayout dynamicallyLayout = null;
                boolean needCreated = true;
                if (json.length() > 1) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < json.length(); j++) {
                        JSONObject classesJson = json.getJSONObject(j);
                        String name = classesJson.getString("name");
                                    classChbx = new CheckBox(ctx);
                                    classChbx.setText(name);
                        if (value == 1) classChbx.setChecked(true);

                        if (needCreated) {
                                dynamicallyLayout = new LinearLayout(ctx);
                                dynamicallyLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
                                holder.llChbTypes.addView(dynamicallyLayout);
                                needCreated = false;
                            }else {
                                if (j % 3 == 0) {
                                    needCreated = true;
                                    dynamicallyLayout.addView(classChbx);
                                    dynamicallyLayout = null;

                                    break;
                                }

                            }
                        if (dynamicallyLayout != null)
                            dynamicallyLayout.addView(classChbx);



                    }
                }else {
                    classChbx = new CheckBox(ctx);
                    classChbx.setText(json.getJSONObject(0).getString("name"));
                    holder.llChbTypes.addView(classChbx);

                }
```

but it look for low resolution like: item1, item2, item3.. that's all!

Comment: What's the actual difference between what *you have* and what *you need*? I don't see any relevant one.

Comment: like nop77svk said... what are you asking?? what you have is the same as what you say you need..

Comment: @nop77svk spaces ... between *item* and *number* :)

Comment: are you asking about margins? and what's these items? and what you are asking for? at least add screenshots.

Comment: updated. it was for SO marking

Comment: @Selvin, edit your question (via the "edit" link below) and clearly explain what you just explained in your comment. Also, always use code formatting feature of the question editor for these cases.

Comment: You should use tag for inflating your LinearLayout and an xml file for inflating CheckBoxes, then find LinearLayout by tag and then get your xml file in which you put CheckBox and add this CheckBox to your LinearLayout.

Comment: @RahulPatidar i have only one Linearlayout(vertical), i need to add dynamically horizontal layout when checkbox item in each row == 3

Comment: yeah I know and you need not create LinearLayout again and again, just create two xml files, one for LinearLayout and one for CheckBox and use this concept

Answer (score 0):

I have used this approach in my code.

```
for ( int i = 0 ; i < 4 ; i ++ )
{

    LinearLayout layoutInWhichToAdd= (LinearLayout) rootView
                            .findViewById(R.id.layoutInWhichToAdd);

    View toadd= orderDetails.getLayoutInflater().inflate(
                            R.layout.include_items_invieworder, layoutInWhichToAdd,
                            false);

    layoutInWhichToAdd.addView(toadd);
}
```